# How to save an access report with a custom name that is pulled out of the report?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to save the PDF file with a custom name. This name should include a parameter/value from the report.

I need to generate several reports like this so I need a differentiation which I guess the `Member_ID` field will provide. I did search a lot on the web, but I am not able to implement any of it.

The code which I have now looks like this:

```
Private Sub Create_PDF_Click()

Dim myPath As String Dim strReportName As String

DoCmd.OpenReport "Proof_Graphs", acViewPreview

myPath = "C:\Proofs\"

strReportName = Proof_Graphs.[MEMBER_ID] + "-" + ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True DoCmd.Close acReport, "Proof_Graphs"

End Sub
```

I am getting an object not found error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
`Reports!ReportName!FieldName` to access the control box for the value on the report.

```
Private Sub Create_PDF_Click()
Dim myPath As String Dim strReportName As String
Dim memberID As String

DoCmd.OpenReport "Proof_Graphs", acViewPreview

memberID = Reports!Proof_Graphs.[MEMBER_ID]'to access the field for the value on the report

myPath = "C:\Proofs\"

strReportName = memberID +  ".pdf"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, myPath + strReportName, True DoCmd.Close acReport, "Proof_Graphs"

End Sub
```